# Civievent 'Cancel' clarification - does 'Cancel' generate a refund / balance

Tags: civievent, workflow

I've recently had to deal with cancelled event and refunds.  At the moment my workflow is to:

1. Issue a refund via the payment process (PayPal)
2. PayPal updates contribution with refund transaction.
3. I then 'Cancel' the event registration for the contact.

I suspect it's not the case, but I'm seeking clarification on this following:

If I do it in reverse and first 'Cancel' a contact from an Event, does it automatically issue a refund with the payment processor?

If not, does that leave a Balance associated with that contact/contribution?  Can I apply (how do I apply) that balance to future events?

Any insight appreciated.

Much thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Civi won't cancel/refund the payment automatically at Paypal when a payment is cancelled in Civi. It's the other way around when a payment is cancelled at Paypal it sends a notification to Civi about the payment. Civi based on the notification updates/cancels the payment in Civi.

So you should be doing

1. Issue a refund via the payment process (PayPal)
2. PayPal updates contribution with refund transaction.
3. I then 'Cancel' the event registration for the contact.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.  It's as I suspected, but wanted to confirm before I started smashing buttons :)  Much appreciated.